# Can you have a sub sub domain?

Tags: domain-name-system, subdomain

Can you have DNS records with sub sub domains?

E.g.: www.blog.domain_name.com?

What about a sub sub wild card domain? At the same time supporting *.domain_name.com?

E.g.: *.blog.domain_name.com?

Comment: As an aside, underscores are not allowed in DNS hostnames:

http://domainkeys.sourceforge.net/underscore.html

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Absolutely. So long as you can put records in the DNS you can make that happen. Go to town.

Comment: What about a sub sub wild card domain?

E.g.: *.blog.domain_name.com?

Comment: Yes.  And.. 15!

Comment: Sorry for asking so many complex questions, I have a complex DNS system that I need to get up and running.

Answer (score 2):

The sub domains are handled differently depending on the browser.  Firefox will interpret *.domain.com literally as anything.domain.com.  So www.domain.com and www.blog.domain.com are both handled by the one entry.  IE handles wildcards only for that portion of the FQDN.  So you would have one for *.domain.com that would match www.domain.com or blog.domain.com and *.*.domain.com that would match www.blog.domain.com or www.somethingelse.domain.com.

Comment: so for the SEO, how the sub sub domain is treated? Say I have www.blog.example.com so which one is treated as the primary domain name - is it BLOG or is it EXAMPLE ?

Comment: "will interpret *.domain.com literally as anything.domain.com" well... not _literally_